# how to write a shell script for printing values in csv file if they are in specific range?

Tags: shell

Let's say we have a csv file filled with time and temperature reading, we have to print the particular time and temperature if the reading is not in 30 to 35 range along with total number of lines minus header and problem values we printed.

while IFS="," read -r column1 column2
do
if [ "${Temp}" > 35 ]; then
echo "Time : $column1" "Temp : $column2"
fi
done <  <(tail -n +2 parse22.csv)

which prints the whole file. i want the time and temp that are not in range of 30 to 35,total number of records and printed number of records

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a few sample lines of CSV. Any reason not to use `awk`?

Comment: `if [ "${Temp}" > 35 ]` executes the command `[ "${Temp}" ]` with output redirected to the file 35.  `>` is a redirection, not a greater-than operator.

Comment: Please click [edit] and select your code with the mouse. Then click `{}` in the formatting toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format it as code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#To keep count of entries that comes under given condition

count=0

#Using while loop to separate the csv file into column through IFS and read command 

while IFS=, read -r Time Temp 

do

#Condition for passing

if [ $Temp -lt 30 ] || [ $Temp -gt 35 ]; 

then

echo "$Time $Temp"  

#Printing the specified value

((++count))  

#Adding the bad entry value to calculate

fi

done <   <(tail -n +2 data1.csv) 

#Ignoring the header and location csv file 

echo ">> we found ${count} bad entries"

#Printing the value**
```

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted, uncommented and not very helpful to future readers. Please click [edit] and try to improve it. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).